# On the Laplacian for radially symmetric functions (prove that $\triangle u(0) = 0$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The expression for the Laplacian of a radially symmetric $C^2$ function defined on $\mathbb{R}^N$ is 
$$\triangle u = u''(r) + \frac{N-1}{r}u'(r)$$

(where $N$ is the space dimension).

How can I prove that $$\triangle u(0) = 0\ ?$$

Comment: Solve the ODE:  $\frac{u''}{u'} = - \frac{N-1}{r}$. See what soutions are possible based on $N$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts That's one approach (which I've already done). However, I'm more interested in proving it *a priori*.

Comment: Why do you expect this to be true? Is $u(r) = r^2 = x^2 + \ldots + z^2$ not a counterexample?

Comment: A special case would be $N=3$ and $u$ the electrostatic potential of a point charge. Then $u$ has a Dirac delta function singularity at the origin.

Comment: Using the same name for different functions is a $\text{Bad Idea}^\text{TM}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $u(x)=g(|x|)$ and assume that $u$ is $C^2$. Then you have $\frac{u(\pm t e_i)-u(0)}{\pm t}=\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{\pm t}$. Letting $t\to 0$ you get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(0)=\pm g'(0)$ and so $g'(0)=0$. So $\nabla u(0)=0$. 
If $x\ne0$, by the chain rule  $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x)=g'(|x|)\frac{x_i}{|x|}$  and so for $t>0$,
$$\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(t e_i)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(0)}{t}=\frac{g'(t)-0}{t}.$$
Letting $t\to 0$ you get that there exists $g''(0)=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}(0)$. Hence, $\Delta u(0)=Ng''(0)$. 
So to have $u$ of class $C^2$ you need $g$ of class $C^2$ with $g'(0)=0$ and no restrictions on $g''(0)$.

If you take $u(x)=|x|^2$, you get that $u$ is radial and $C^\infty$ and $\Delta u(0)=2N\ne 0$. 
Are you assuming that $u$ is harmonic?

Comment: I don't understand why you have "and so $g'(0)=0$. So $\nabla u(0)=0$."

Comment: you have $a=b$ and $a=-b$ so necessarily $a=b=0$. Is this the question?